# How to display google+ local reviews and ratings of a particular business on my website?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am developing an application like http://www.reputation.com/ 
User have to input the URLs like https://plus.google.com/105836802564090875429/about and i have to fetch corresponding review/ratings and have to display on my screen.

All the process will be automated. As we have google place detail api available(https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetails) but here we have to provide reference of a place.

Now i am stuck that how to find reference from my url(https://plus.google.com/105836802564090875429/about)?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these two questions: [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004406/how-to-fetch-review-and-ratings-from-google-local) & [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757631/how-to-display-google-local-reviews-and-ratings-of-a-particular-business-on-my)

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question.  It was closed for a reason ... both times.

Comment: @StephenC: Please let me know the reason for closing the question, so that i can stop reposting it in future.

Comment: Well basically it is a combination of asking a vague and barely comprehensible question, and not showing that you've done your research.  And then reposting the same question which is a sure fire way to get ignored.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a bonus.  It might attract the right kind of attention to your Question.  But to be honest if people cannot understand it they are unlikely to be able to answer it.

Comment: I have done alot research on this and also got a little success but i am stuck on a point mentioned in the question. I tried to get help from google itself but they have given stackover's link to post the problem. I was thinking that people shall help me to resolve this issue but... :(

Comment: And if you think that people are able to understand the question, you can modify the language also if possible for you.